# Website thumnails (screenshots)

Tags: php, image-processing, thumbnails, centos

I want to create website thumbnails (screenshots) using php. I have a dedicated server running centos 5.5 so I can install software on it.

I need a free solution to create thumbnails of websites on a production server without running X server. (If I was to run X server how much difference would it make to the performance).

I would also appreciate if you could provide me with any free web services which could help me get the website thumnails and download them to my server.

Comment: Take a look at the PHP GD Library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I used it when I was building a site that required thumbnails of other websites:

http://www.thumboo.com/

Note that you will need to sign up for the API.

Hope this helps and that I understood your question

Comment: are there any software for linux

Answer (score 4):

To take a virtual screenshot of a website, use [`khtml2png`](http://khtml2png.sourceforge.net/). It uses libkhtml, the rendering engine used by the konquerer brower, and imagemagick.

Comment: I means thumbnails of websites by "website thumbnails"

Comment: @user Oh, totally different question. You should update the question to make this clear.

Comment: thanks. I get errors when running khtml2png. Any other alternatives which can produce good website thumbnails and can be run through php exec()

Comment: @user If you have trouble running `khtml2png` in the terminal even, then I suggest posting along with errors on superuser.com . It's a sister site to Stack Overflow aimed at questions like this.